# TFTP boot of a bare-metal program on imx53-QSB

Tags: embedded, bootloader, u-boot, bare-metal, tftp

I'm working on a **bare-metal** program on my imx53-QSB. I wrote de program and build it correctly and succeeded to boot it form the SD card. But now I want to boot using **TFTP**. I put U-Boot on my SD card, and created my TFTP server on my computer in which I put my boot file *kernel.imx* I transferred after that my file to the board using

> tftp 0x90000000 kernel.imx

done
Bytes transferred = 11264 (2c00 hex)

After that I try to boot using the *kernel.imx* that i transferred using

> go 0x90000000

but it stays stuck in this message : ## Starting application at 0x90000000 ...

I also tried using kernel.elf, kernel.img and kernel.bin

Any idea of how to solve this ? Thanks

Comment: Which kernel are you using? Could be that it needs DTB to be loaded before to start your kernel.

Comment: @LPs I am not using any kernel, it's just the name of my bare-metal program boot file

Comment: Could you post the script that makes your app working from SD?

Comment: @LPs I used `dd if=kernel.imx of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=512 seek=2` I put the SD on my board and it boot correctly

Comment: Ok. In that way your app is starting without uboot, is it right?

Comment: @LPs No. If I use `dd if=kernel.imx of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=512 seek=2` i don't need u-boot, I put juste the kernel.imx in my SD card. what I want to do, is use U-Boot : `dd if=uboot.imx of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=512 seek=2` and after that, from U-Boot, i boot the kernel.imx using tftp

Comment: I think is something related to your app or to the linker. Is your code relocable? Is your code linked to start from address 0x90000000?

Comment: @LPs Yes, it's linked to start at 0x90000000. Concerning the _relocable_ point, I don't know what it means

Comment: If your app start from 0x90000000, relocable doesn't matter. Then, I guess your app is trying to configure something that u-boot as reconfigured. I mean that if it is your SoC boot ROM that start our app, all perfireals and modules are at reset/default status and all go well. When  is uboot that load your app some modules (such as MMU, DDR ...) are already configured and maybe your app is not able to re.confiure those in the correct way    to run.

Comment: @LPs huuuum I see!  so what is the solution you think ? Remove the configuration from the app ? Or ... ?

Comment: In this case the question is too broad. All can be in conflicts with all. You must debug your app with a debugger and try to understand what is going wrong. I suggest to start stopping u-boot and load app from your SD card and launch it with a debugger.

Comment: @LPs it works just by removing all the configuration code from the app ;)

Comment: Well done! Then you can, if you are intested, check your config step by step to understand what is the critical config.

Comment: @LPs Ok, i'll do that! Thank you man